# Maven dependencies removed in eclipse after project update

Tags: eclipse, maven

I have a spring maven project created in eclipse...
When I add new dependencies to the pom file, I have to update the project (right click on project->maven->update project)...
when I do this the maven dependencies are automatically removed I have to add them manually (project properties->deployment assembly).
Any ideas on how to solve this ?

Comment: Don't add them manually. First, try to build your project with Maven (run as -> Maven build). If this goes through, the Eclipse error will probably be gone. If not, you will get some error message which you can examine.

Comment: have you found a solution to your problem? I have the same problem